# Allow one hypen somewhere in the middle of a name

Tags: regex

I am using this regex to validate names:

```
/^[A-Za-zàèéáäÄüÜöÖ]+$/
```

How can I add a rule to allow one hypen (`-`) ? Sometimes people have hypens in their name, e.g. "Hans-Meier"

I tried:

```
/^[A-Za-zàèéáäÄüÜöÖ[-{1}]]+$/
```

The hypen should not be at the start or at the end.

Comment: Some people have multiple hyphens. If it's really names you're after, don't validate. Make them validate by making the consequence of getting your name wrong undesirable.

Comment: Use `/^[A-Za-zàèéáäÄüÜöÖ]+(?:-[A-Za-zàèéáäÄüÜöÖ]+)?$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment is more philosophical. From the technical side, try this:

```
/^[A-Za-zàèéáäÄüÜöÖ]+-?[A-Za-zàèéáäÄüÜöÖ]+$/
```

Comment: I propose change -? part for -* so it will match zero o more hypens solving the situation you comment in the question: "Some people have multiple hyphens": ^[A-Za-zàèéáäÄüÜöÖ]+-*[A-Za-zàèéáäÄüÜöÖ]+$ Demo: https://regex101.com/r/RhosOA/2

Comment: @Pablo. #1, that's not what OP asked, #2, -* means any number of *consecutive* hyphens, which is pointless.

Comment: ok @Mad Physicist I understood that when you said "Some people have multiple hyphens" you were meaning xxx xx-xx xx--xx xx-(n)xx and that is what solve -* (zero or more numbers of -). I misunderstood your comment.